# Autosizing Cell After Subview Added Programatically

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

In my code, I'm adding a subview to a subview inside each cell. Each nested subview can be of various sizes. The nested subview is not causing the cell to increase its height, so the subview is getting cut off. How can I get the cell to increase in height based on the nested subview?

```
import WSTagsField
class Search {
    @IBOutlet weak var searchResultsTableView: UITableView!
    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        searchResultsTableView.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
        searchResultsTableView.estimatedRowHeight = 100      
    }

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var availableTagsString = ""
    var matchingAvailableTagsWithSearch = [String]()
    let availableTagsArray = documentKeysWithinRadius[indexPath.row]["available_tags"] as! [String]
    for i in 0...availableTagsArray.count - 1
    {
        if searchTags.contains(availableTagsArray[i])
        {
            availableTagsString += "\(availableTagsArray[i]) "
            matchingAvailableTagsWithSearch.append(availableTagsArray[i])
        }
    }
    availableTagsString = availableTagsString.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
    let cell : MyCustomCell = self.searchResultsTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! MyCustomCell

    let tagsField = MyFunctions().createTagsField(fontSize: 14.0)

    //add the view only tags
    if (matchingAvailableTagsWithSearch.count > 0)
    {
        for i in 0...matchingAvailableTagsWithSearch.count - 1
        {
            tagsField.addTag(matchingAvailableTagsWithSearch[i])
        }
    }

    tagsField.readOnly = true

    tagsField.frame = cell.tableCellTagsView.bounds

//tableCellTagsView is a UIView in the prototype cell
    cell.tableCellTagsView.addSubview(tagsField)
    return cell
}

}
```

Constraints
[image]

Answer (score 0):

To resize a tableView you need to set constraints for any view added , I think the best way is to use a vertical stackView for that by hooking it's top , left , bottom and right constraints and use

```
cell.stackTags.addArranagedSubview(tagsField)
```

and give it a height constraint

```
tagsField.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant:50).isActive = true
```

> If the element you add is a `UILabel`/`UIButton` that has an intrinsic content size then no need for the height constraint

Also this

```
tagsField.frame = cell.tableCellTagsView.bounds
```

won't correctly get the real bounds as it's not yet known , plus frame-layout won't resize the cell

Plus to clear anything either by implement `prepareForReuse` inside the cell subclass , or remove all previously added subviews with

```
cell.stackTags.subviews.forEach { $0.removeFromsuperview() }
```

after this line

```
let cell:MyCustomCell = self.searchResultsTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! MyCustomCell
```

With no need for `:MyCustomCell`